# FindFirstHtmlVersion just returning more html

Tags: html, email, client, pop3, openpop

The openPop function just returns a load of HTML which is difficult to find a way to parse. Has anyone got any ideas on how I should further parse the html so I can get the body of text I need? I've tried getbodyastext method which didn't seem to be of any use.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-

com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char";
    margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-GB link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Test Email for dev_sitehelpdesk<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'>Regards,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'>NAME HERE</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB'>Technical Manager<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used regex to strip out most of the HTML and put in carriage returns. I know you shouldn't use regex to parse html, but this is limited HTML that I just wanted to get rid of. Works fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function I modified from the comment link below:

```
private string GetMessageBodyAsTextNew(Message message)
{//http://www.limilabs.com/blog/tag/html
    string body;
    MessagePart plainTextPart = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
    if (plainTextPart != null)
    {
        // The message had a text/plain version - show that one
        body = plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText();
    }
    else
    {
        // Try to find a body to show in some of the other text versions
        MessagePart html = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();//http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSpecificParts.php
        if (html != null)
        {
            // Save the plain text to a file, database or anything you like
            //body = GetMessageBodyAsText(message);
            body = GetTextFromHtml_Xpath(html.GetBodyAsText());
        }
        else
        {
            body = "The system was unable to get the body text of this message";
        }
    }
    return body;
}
```